# Resizing datagrid column with CanUserResize="True" is not working in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have used the CanUserResize="True" for the datagrid column but i can't able to resize while hover on the column header.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ScenarioExecutables" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" Margin="10" FontSize="14"
                Grid.Row="1" CanUserResizeColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Scenario" Width="1*" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="True">
               <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                    </Style>
               </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
         </DataGridTextColumn>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"  Width="2*" CanUserResize="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I've tested this code and it works. I can resize the first column, the second one can only be resized if the grid is not set to take the full width of the parent container. Could you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: Is it Working..? I cant able to resize the First column itself even the resizing icon(<-->) itself is not displayed on hover.

Comment: Can you post your code in a Window in a new WPF project? This way there can't be interfering styles or other code.

Comment: Reordering is working fine for the same code. resizing alone is not working. Is there any way to stop overriding the style..?

Comment: I am having this datagrid within a grid will it create this issue.? If so the reordering should not work.

Comment: Can you post a simple example where the problem occurs? With this information it is not possible to simulate it.

Comment: I have changed the template style of the datagrid column header will it create a resize problem ..?

Comment: thanks for you contribution.. I found that why that was not working and added the answer below..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since i had changed the Template of the datagrid column header so the resizing will not working properly

so add this code the resizing will work..

```
<Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" Grid.Column="1"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        Width="2" BorderThickness="1"
                                        BorderBrush="{Binding VerticalGridLinesBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                        Cursor="SizeWE"/>
```